# Get URL of hyperlink based on anchortext

Tags: regex

So im trying to get the URL with every link that contains the word blog as an anchor text.

EG:

```
<a href="http://asdas.com/blog">this is our blog</a>
<a href="http://asdas.com/blog">BLOG</a>
<a href="http://asdas.com/blog">   blogging   </a>
```

result: `http://asdas.com/blog`

This works fine, unless there are more html tags in the link...

```
<a class="asdadasd" href="http://asdas.com/blog" id="asdasd">this is our blog</a>
```

Result: `http://asdas.com/blog" id="asdasd`

Here's what i've got

```
(?i)<a.+href="(.*)".*>.*?blog.*?</a>
```

Comment: Can you try to read until last `"` instead of `>` from `href="` so that it will stop and won't read the next tags.

Comment: Do you have to use regex to solve this problem? Parsing HTML with regex is one of those things that you would feel guilty about if you wished it on your worst enemy. Most programming languages have libraries to parse XML (for example, if you're using PHP, there are a few different ways to parse a DOM). You should look into using such a library, and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `?` to make your `(.*)` lazy. Otherwise your `.*` will continue to grab everything that it can until it reaches the final closing `"`.

Try this:

```
(?i)<a.+href="(.*?)".*>.*?blog.*?</a>
```

All I've done is change `(.*)` to `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using RegEx alone is a headache. Never parse HTML documents with RegEx. Do it with [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
var html = `<a href="http://asdas.com/blog">this is our blog</a>
<a href="http://asdas.com/blog">BLOG</a>
<a href="http://asdas.com/blog">   test   </a>`;

var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
var aTags = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('a')

Array.prototype.slice.call(aTags).forEach(function(a) {
   if(a.innerText.match(/blog/i))
     console.log(a.href)
});
```